# Javascript addEventListener within if statement (which checks a state)

Tags: javascript, if-statement, addeventlistener

I am trying to write a simple language game, where the user can begin the game by clicking whether they want to translate or fill gaps. As I want different code to run depending on whether the user has selected translate or gapfill, I thought that having a 'state' variable which is changed depending on the game mode, and then having an eventlistener within an 'if' statement, would work.

I can check on the console that the state is getting set to 0, but the event listener within the if statement doesn't run. It works fine if the 'if' statement isn't there. Is this something to do with the if statement only running at the moment the state is set to 0?

```
let state = 0;

document.querySelector('#translations').addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  state = 1;
  console.log(state);
});
document.querySelector('#gapfill').addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  state = 2;
});

if (state === 1) {
  answerBtn.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    console.log('hello from translations');
    if (document.querySelector('input').value == sentences[quNum].sentence) {
      quNum++;
      displayQu();
    } else {
      sentences.splice(quNum + 5, 0, sentences[quNum]);
      quNum++;
      displayQu();
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`addEventListener` does no more than what its name implies... It adds an event listener.  *When that event happens* (such as when the user clicks on something), the code within the function will be executed.  So this code isn't going to be executed until some later time:

```
state = 1;
```

But *right away* you check the value:

```
if (state === 1)
```

So basically you're doing this:

```
let state = 0;
if (state === 1)
```

Which will never be true.

Instead of conditionally adding the last event listener (based on a condition that won't be met until some future time), always add it but within its function conditionally perform the operation:

```
answerBtn.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  if (state === 1) {
    // the rest of the logic
  }
});
```

That way when that click event happens at a later time there's a chance the other event may have also happened and set the value to `1`.  And if it hasn't, the event listener will still execute but won't do anything because the `if` condition fails.

Answer (score 1):

This can be simplified greatly. There's no need for a state variable and multiple event handlers. Instead, leverage ["event delegation"](https://javascript.info/event-delegation) by setting up just one handler at an ancestor of both buttons. Then when a button is clicked, the event will bubble up to the element that is handling the event. Within the handler, you can determine which button actually triggered the event with [`event.target`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target) and then just proceed as needed.

Here's an example:

```js
// Set up one handler at a common ancestor of both buttons
document.querySelector(".wrapper").addEventListener("click", function(event){
  // Was one of the buttons the thing that caused the event?
  if(event.target.classList.contains("gap")){
    // Do gap stuff here
    console.log("You clicked gap");
  } else if(event.target.classList.contains("translate")){
    // Do translate stuff here
    console.log("You clicked translate");  
  }
});
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <button class="gap">Gap Fill</button>
  <button class="translate">Translate</button>  
</div>
```